# Limit of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification, convexity-inequality

I would need a check on the following exercise:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex function.
>
> - Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} f(x)$ exist
> - Show that if both the limits are finite, then $f$ is constant.

---

*My attempt:*

i ) I know that if $f$ is convex, then $$f(t x_1 + (1-t)x_2)< t f(x_1) + (1-t) f(x_2)$$

If I fix an arbitrary $N>0$, then I have that for $x>x_2 \colon \quad f(x)>N$, thanks to the convexity, therefore this proves the limit to $+ \infty$ is $+\infty$.

The same argument applies to $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x)$: it suffices to note that for $x<x_1 \colon \quad f(x)>N$.

---

ii)

Graphically it's obvious, but I have some problem in make it formal.

If the limit is finite, say $L$, then for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an $M(\varepsilon)$ such that for $$x>M(\varepsilon) \colon \quad |f(x)-L|\leq \varepsilon$$

Assume $f (x) \ne c$. By definition of convexity, it has to hold (for $t \in [0,1]$) $$t f(M)+(1-t)f(M+1) \leq f(t M + (1-t)(M+1))$$

Now, by definition of limit, $f(M)$ and $f(M+1)$ are less than $L-\varepsilon$. Also, the argument in the rhs of the inequality can be simplified:

$$L-\varepsilon <t f(M)+(1-t)f(M+1) \leq f(t M + (1-t)(M+1)) = f(M-t)$$

Therefore $$L-\varepsilon < f(M-t)$$, which is a contradiction because $M-t<M$ and hence it can be greater than $L-\varepsilon$.

So $f$ has to be equal to $c$. Indeed in this case, it is still (trivially) convex, and the limits are of course finite.

Comment: Your argument for (i) seems unsatisfactory to me

Comment: Thanks for the check. How could I improve it? (do you think that (ii) is fine)? @AdamRubinson

Comment: You stated that, "for $x > x_2, f(x) >N$, due to it being convex". But that's not a mathematical proof. That's just an assertion without evidence/reason.

Comment: @AdamRubinson you're right, I was thinking about the graphical representation of a convex function. The fact is that I don't know how to formalize it. Could you give a hint?

Comment: Yeah I don't know the answer. It's not super easy. But I'll give it some thought...

Comment: By the way I'm guessing the first bullet point means, for each of the two limits: the limit exists and is finite, or the limit tends to + infinity or the limit tends to - infinity. You might have to prove each of these 3 cases separately for each limit, so that's 6 cases total.

Comment: In your first argument, you deduce that $f$ tends to $+\infty$ in $+\infty$, which has no reason to be true. For example $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is convex and tends to $0$. A convex function can have any limit in $+\infty$.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't realise that was what his argument was saying, but you are right, TheSilverDoe.

Answer (score 1):

convexity usually means "$\le$", not "$\lt$" (otherwise it's "strictly convex").

You don't want to show that f always goes to infinity, because it need not.

Start with $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Suppose first there are two points $x\lt y$ with $f(x)\lt f(y)$.  Then we *can* show that f goes to infinity.  We can suppose without loss of generality that $x=0$ and $f(x)=0$ (if not, just slide and shift f until it does.  It won't change the behaviour we are interested in.)

Consider some $z>y$.  Since $y>x=0$, then $z=y/t$ for some $0<t<1$.  So by convexity, $$tf(z)=tf(y/t)+(1-t)f(0)\ge f(t(y/t)+(1-t)0)=f(y)$$
So $f(z)\ge f(y)/t$.  As $z\rightarrow \infty$ it's clear that $t$ goes to $0$, so $f(y)/t\rightarrow\infty$ (remember $f(y)>0$) and therefore so does $f(z)$.
Therefore in this case $f$ increases to infinity.

Otherwise our supposition was false, so f must be either constant or else non-constant and monotone decreasing.  Suppose it's the latter.  Again, move the origin so that $f(0)=0$.  Then $f(1)<0$ and it's easy to show by the convexity property that $f(t)\le t f(1)$ and so $f$ goes off to minus infinity.

You can then repeat the argument by symmetry, for the behaviour as $x\rightarrow-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** try to prove that a convex function is either decreasing, either increasing, either decreasing then increasing.