Convex function on $(0,\infty)$ has right-limit at $0$
Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ denote a convex function. Then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists (it is either finite or equal to $+\infty$).
Such a claim is made in Liese and Vajda, "On Divergences and Informations in Statistics and Information Theory" (see the paragraph surrounding Equation (9)) and also in Liese and Vajda,
"f-divergences: Sufficiency, deficiency and testing of hypotheses" (see the beginning of page 135).
In both papers, the authors justify the claim by invoking the representation $f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^b f'_+(s) ds$, where $f'_+$ denotes the right-derivative of $f$. Such a representation exists since $f$ is absolutely continuous on compact intervals. However I fail to understand how this shows the existence of
the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$.
I think that maybe their claim is wrong, and in that case I would like to see a counterexample.

You can argue similarly as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3794828/42969

@MartinR Thank you. Since $f'+$ is nondecreasing, one should consider cases: either $f'+$ is always $\geq 0$, or it is $\leq 0$ in a neighborhood of $0$ . Then as suggested in this answer, we can describe the monotonicity of $f$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Is this the proof you had in mind ?

Essentially. You don't need the (one-sided) derivatives. Either $f$ is increasing everywhere, or it is decreasing on an interval $(0, a]$.

Suppose $f$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$. Define the function
$$g(t)=\frac{f(1)-f(t)}{1-t}, \qquad 0<t<1$$
As $f$ is convex, for any $0<x<u<1$
$$
f(u)\leq (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(1)
$$
with $0<\lambda=\frac{u-x}{1-x}<1$. It follows that
$$g(x)=\frac{f(1)-f(x)}{1-x}\leq \frac{f(1)-f(u)}{1-u}=g(u)$$
This shows that $g$ is monotone nondecreasing. Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}g(x)$ exists as an extender real number in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$; hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}f(x)$ exists as an extended number in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ for
$$f(t)=f(1)-(1-t)g(t), \qquad 0<t<1.$$

Either $f$ is nondecreasing, or there exists $0<a<b$ such that $f(a)>f(b)$.
In that last case, $f$ must be decreasing over the interval $(0,a]$. Indeed, since $f$ is convex,
$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<0$$
holds for every $x<y\leq a$.
Thus in both cases, $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists in $[-\infty, \infty]$.
In order to show that this limit cannot be $-\infty$, it suffices to prove that $f$ is bounded below in a neighborhood of $0$.
Indeed, when $0<x\leq 1$, we have $1\leq \frac{x+2}2 \leq \frac 32$, and since $f$ is continuous over the interval $[1,\frac 32]$, it is bounded below there by some $m$. Next,  $$m\leq f(\frac{x+2}2)\leq \frac 12 f(x) + \frac 12 f(2),$$
thus $f$ is bounded below over $(0,1]$ by $2m-f(2)$.

An additional common fact when studying $f$-divergences is that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$.
We give a similar proof. Either $f$ is nonincreasing, or there exists $0<a<b$ such that $f(b)>f(a)$. In the second case,
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-b) + f(b) \leq f(x)$$
holds for every $x\geq b$, hence
$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.
